# Macbook is running, but black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a Macbook Pro (2015). When I switch on, I can hear the fan noice but screen remains black, no backlight (No light on the Apple logo in back). I checked brightness, restarted mac several times, reset the System Management Controller, followed these [steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267) but no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT: Battery is dead

Comment: This may seem strange, but shine a light through the Apple logo on the back and see if there is anything displayed in that small area.  If so, the screen is working but the backlight may have lost power and would need physical repair.  Perhaps an external monitor can get you by in the meantime.

Comment: @bjbk Will do. BTW my mac's battery is dead. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @bjbk has a good suggestion that super easy to confirm.  One more question... Do you get the boot chime?  If it's plugged in, it should still boot even if the battery is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try resetting NVRAM and PRAM. They store system settings that might be related to the problem.

> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P and R. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

[Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063)

Comment: I followed those too, but no luck. The screen didnt even showing anything

Comment: Just FYI..it's NVRAM. PRAM was on PowerPC Macs like the G3/G4/G5 models.  NVRAM is for Intel and ARM Macs.  Secondly, there's no setting in NVRAM that prevents a screen from turning on - the logo being dark points to a physical issue.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to find a way to plug in an external monitor. That will tell you the depth of the issue: just video or the whole thing.